# Decaying buffer around points

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have a raster which represents a series of patchy habitats. Each patch of habitat has a value of 1. All other cells in the raster are set as NA. I would like to apply a buffer around the points as you would using `raster::buffer` but need some extra functionality.

I would like the buffer to 'decay' as you move away from a patch. So if a patch=1 and the buffer is set to, say, 3 mapunits, I would like the buffer to have decayed to zero by the time mapunits=3. If two patches are close enough together such that their buffers overlap, I would need to apply some function to decide the value in the overlapping cells (e.g. sum, mean, first, last etc.).

I have included below some code which illustrates the expected outcome. As I can't find any solution online (searching for "decreasing buffers" or "decaying buffer"), I can't provide more code to help, sorry.

```
focal = raster(nrow=5, ncol=5, crs=NA, xmn=0, xmx=5, ymn=0, ymx=5)
focal[] = c(0.33,NA,NA,NA,0.33,
            0.66,0.33,NA,0.33,0.66,
            1,0.66,0.33,0.66,1,
            0.66,0.33,NA,0.33,0.66,
            0.33,NA,NA,NA,0.33)
plot(focal)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a combination of `distance`  and `buffer` like this:

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10, crs="+proj=utm +zone=1", xmn=0, xmx=5, ymn=0, ymx=5)
r[c(39,52)] <- 1
```

Solution

```
d <- distance(r)
b <- buffer(r, 1.5)
m <- mask(d, b)
```

Display

```
plot(m)
text(m, digits=1)
```

[image: buffer and distance]